# AngularJS orderby not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular directive to orderBy on table rows, with the data coming as an array of objects from a service.

```
<tr ng-repeat="album in vm.albums | orderBy: album.data.title">

    <td>{{album.data.title}}</td>
    <td>{{album.data.date}}</td>
    <td>{{album.data.type}}</td>
    <td>{{album.data.username}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here's what my `vm.albums` array looks like:

```
vm.albums ---> [>Object1, >Object2, >Object3......]
```

And each object looks like the foll:

```
Object1 ---> {slug: "my-title", data: Object}
Object2 ---> {slug: "beta-title", data: Object}
Object3 ---> {slug: "alpha-title", data: Object}
```

And the object `Object1.data` or any object in the vm.albums array looks like the following:

```
Object1.data ---> {title: "My Title", date: "2015-04-06", type: "Blue", username: 'rust'}
Object2.data ---> {title: "Beta Title", date: "2012-04-07", type: "Orange", username: 'badname'}
Object3.data ---> {title: "Alpha Title", date: "2013-09-06", type: "Lemons", username: 'xerox'}
```

I still don't get the right sorted `<td>` in my table using the `orderBy` I am using. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any clue ?

Comment: if slug is the same as data.title why cant you just do orderBy: album.slug? I think that might work better, because my guess is angular orderBy does not work with a nested property, unless you write a custom function for it

Comment: Updated my post. The slug will be different for all. Each object in the array has a different data. This is an array of objects.

Comment: Instead of `| orderBy: album.data.title` try `| orderBy 'data.title'`

Comment: I tried `data.title` also. No change

Comment: try `<tr ng-repeat="album in vm.albums | orderBy: 'data.title'">

    <td>{{album.data.title}}</td>
    <td>{{album.data.date}}</td>
    <td>{{album.data.type}}</td>
    <td>{{album.data.username}}</td>
</tr>`

Comment: AAAAHHHH Dang, I knew I was missing the `single quotes' around the data.title which is why it failed.

Comment: @ElenaDBA can you post your answer so I can mark it as correct answer ?

Comment: Thanks. Will mark it as right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
<tr ng-repeat="album in vm.albums | orderBy: 'data.title'">
  <td>{{album.data.title}}</td>
  <td>{{album.data.date}}</td>
  <td>{{album.data.type}}</td>
  <td>{{album.data.username}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4):

take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

you should be passing an expression not a variable

> Returns an array containing the items from the specified collection, ordered by a comparator function based on the values computed using the expression predicate.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.vm = {
      albums: [{
        slug: "m",
        data: {
          title: "My Title",
          date: "2015-04-06",
          type: "Blue",
          username: 'rust'
        }
      }, {
        slug: "m",
        data: {
          title: "Beta Title",
          date: "2012-04-07",
          type: "Orange",
          username: 'badname'
        }
      }, {
        slug: "m",
        data: {
          title: "Another Title",
          date: "2015-04-06",
          type: "Blue",
          username: 'rust'
        }
      }, ]
    }

  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="album in vm.albums | orderBy: 'data.title'">
        <td>{{album.data.title}}</td>
        <td>{{album.data.date}}</td>
        <td>{{album.data.type}}</td>
        <td>{{album.data.username}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep. Thanks. Your answer was also correct. Elena answered it first, I think. But Ive upvoted your answer. It's helpful :)