# Angular orderBy to also order the original array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to Angular, I ham using angular's `orderBy` on a column header as the code snippet mentioned in my earlier post: [AngularJS orderby not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38338510/angularjs-orderby-not-working-as-expected/)

Now in my controller, the array `vm.albums` is still going to maintain its original order as it came from the backend and orderBy directive is just going to order the DOM as per the sorting criteria. I want to know how do I extract the top row after every re-ordering from the DOM ? This is needed for me to display another set of details depending on which the first row in the table is. Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filters from javascript [`$filter('orderBy')(collection, expression, reverse, comparator)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

```
vm.top = $filter('orderBy')(vm.albums, 'data.title')[0]
```

This will sort `albums` by `data.title` and extract top row.

Comment: Thanks. So that works. But I have the header to do both, sort and reverse sort. So if `reverseSort` variable is true then it sorts backwards:
     <tr ng-repeat="album in vm.albums | orderBy:'data.genre':reverseSort">
How do I specify the reverseSort condition in the above expression >?

Comment: Take a look at the third argument. It does exactly what you are looking for. Suppose you have `vm.reverseSort` then `vm.top = $filter('orderBy')(vm.albums, 'data.title', vm.reverseSort)[0]`

Comment: Thanks. This helps:)